# Extract & transform data from Sql Server to MongoDB periodically

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, replication, etl

I have a Sql Server database which is used to store data coming from a lot of  different sources (writers).

I need to provide users with some aggregated data, however in Sql Server this data is stored in several different tables and querying it is too slow ( 5 tables join with several million rows in each table, one-to-many ).

I'm currently thinking that the best way is to extract data, transform it and store it in a separate database (let's say MongoDB, since it will be used only for read).

I don't need the data to be live, just not older that 24 hours compared to the 'master' database.

But what's the best way to achieve this? Can you recommend any tools for it (preferably free) or is it better to write your own piece of software and schedule it to run periodically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend respecting the NIH principle here, reading and transforming data is a well understood exercise. There are several free ETL tools available, with different approaches and focus. [Pentaho](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/) (ex Kettle) and [Talend](https://www.talend.com/products/data-integration/data-integration-open-studio/) are UI based examples. There are other ETL frameworks like [Rhino ETL](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-etl) that merely hand you a set of tools to write your transformations in code. Which one you prefer depends on your knowledge and, unsurprisingly, preference. If you are not a developer, I suggest using one of the UI based tools. I have used Pentaho ETL in a number of smaller data warehousing scenarios, it can be scheduled by using operating system tools (cron on linux, task scheduler on windows). More complex scenarios can make use of the Pentaho PDI repository server, which allows central storage and scheduling of your jobs and transformations. It has connectors for several database types, including MS SQL Server. I haven't used Talend myself, but I've heard good things about it and it should be on your list too.

The main advantage of sticking with a standard tool is that once your demands grow, you'll already have the tools to deal with them. You may be able to solve your current problem with a small script that executes a complex select and inserts the results into your target database. But experience shows those demands seldom stay the same for long, and once you have to incorporate additional databases or maybe even some information in text files, your scripts become less and less maintainable, until you finally give in and redo your work in a standard toolset designed for the job.